# How to add an item to list in cycle in Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

I'm studying Elixir/Phoenix and there is a task in front of me. I need to filter results from database in a cycle. Something like this:

```
user = Repo.get_by(User, api_token: token)
rooms = Repo.all(Room)
result = []
if !Enum.empty?(rooms) do
  Enum.each rooms, fn room ->
    users = Poison.decode!(room.users)
    if Enum.member?(users, user.id) do
       result = result ++ [room]
    end
  end
end
json(conn, %{"rooms" => result})
```

But this case don't allow me to append items to list, why? Because this is a functional language...
Is there a way to append items to list in a cycle?

Oh yeah, maybe you ask me "Why you just don't get objects from the database by user id?" I'll say that the room.users store json array encoded in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to select some items from a list, you can use `Enum.filter/2`. You can also use the `in` operator instead of `Enum.member?/2`.

```
user = Repo.get_by(User, api_token: token)
rooms = Repo.all(Room)
result = Enum.filter(rooms, fn room ->
  user.id in Poison.decode!(room.users)
end)
```

You can also use `for` instead of `Enum.filter/2`:

```
result = for room <- rooms, user.id in Poison.decode!(room.users), do: room
```

Comment: Thanks. It's work, but really is there a way how to filter it in a cycle? It seems to me that this will not work in all cases

Comment: If you want to make arbitrary changes to a variable while iterating through a list, you can use `Enum.reduce/3`. Here are some of my answers that use `Enum.reduce/3`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a320615%20%5belixir%5d%20Enum.reduce.